# Predict values using group_by in R

Tags: r, regression

I want to create a column with the predicted values of a regression - previously grouped.

I have tried this:

Data

```
city<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b","a")
gender<-c("male","female","female","male","male","female","male")
age<-c(24,25,26,78,65,34,23)
death<-c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0)

df<-data.frame(city,gender,age,death)
```

Code:

```
df_1<-df%>%
  group_by(city)%>%
  glm(death~gender+age,data=df,family="poisson")%>%
  mutate(death_p=predict(glm))
```

Result

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ., data = df, weights = death ~  : 
  invalid type (language) for variable '(weights)'
```

Comment: Looks like the variable type you have specified for the weights parameter is wrong. Are you using "weights" as a variable too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do it using `do()` and minor changes like to include the formula argument in the glm() function, weights could be set to NULL:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  do(data.frame(., death_p = predict(glm(death ~ gender + age, data = ., family = "poisson"))))

  city  gender   age death   death_p
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 a     male      24     0 -2.31e+ 1
2 a     female    25     0 -2.31e+ 1
3 a     female    26     1  0       
4 a     male      23     0 -4.61e+ 1
5 b     male      78     1 -2.84e-14
6 b     male      65     0 -2.33e+ 1
7 b     female    34     0 -2.33e+ 1
```

Answer (score 2):

1. "Never" use `df` in a pipe based off of `df`. In any case where the data is appended, filtered, augmented, or (as in this case) *grouped*, reusing `df` is not going to give you the intended results. Use `cur_data()` instead.
2. We can store the model as a list-column. In this case since we don't summarize it, it's a *little* inefficient since it'll store redundant copies of the model in each row within a group, but ... we can live with that for now.

Try this:

```r
out <- df %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  mutate(
    mdl = list(glm(death ~ gender + age, data=cur_data(), family="poisson")), 
    pred = predict(mdl[[1]], newdata = cur_data(), family = "poisson")
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
out
# Warning: Problem while computing `mdl = list(glm(death ~ gender + age, data = cur_data(), family = "poisson"))`.
# ℹ glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred
# ℹ The warning occurred in group 1: city = "a".
# # A tibble: 7 × 6
#   city  gender   age death mdl         pred
#   <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <list>     <dbl>
# 1 a     male      24     0 <glm>  -2.31e+ 1
# 2 a     female    25     0 <glm>  -2.31e+ 1
# 3 a     female    26     1 <glm>   0       
# 4 b     male      78     1 <glm>  -2.84e-14
# 5 b     male      65     0 <glm>  -2.33e+ 1
# 6 b     female    34     0 <glm>  -2.33e+ 1
# 7 a     male      23     0 <glm>  -4.61e+ 1
```

You can do other things with the `mdl` column, such as extract some summaries:

```r
out %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  summarize(smry = list(summary(mdl[[1]]))) %>%
  pull(smry)
# [[1]]
# Call:
# glm(formula = death ~ gender + age, family = "poisson", data = cur_data())
# Deviance Residuals: 
#          1           2           3           4  
# -1.389e-05  -1.389e-05   0.000e+00  -2.110e-08  
# Coefficients:
#               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept)    -599.62 1606083.51       0        1
# gendermale       23.06  138127.43       0        1
# age              23.06   61772.44       0        1
# (Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)
#     Null deviance: 2.7726e+00  on 3  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 3.8564e-10  on 1  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 8
# Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 22
# [[2]]
# Call:
# glm(formula = death ~ gender + age, family = "poisson", data = cur_data())
# Deviance Residuals: 
# [1]  0  0  0
# Coefficients:
#               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept)    -84.248 195033.586       0        1
# gendermale     -55.568 245825.832       0        1
# age              1.793   5357.985       0        1
# (Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)
#     Null deviance: 2.1972e+00  on 2  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 3.0330e-10  on 0  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 8
# Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a data.table version

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, death_p:=exp(predict(glm(death~age+gender, family="poisson"))), city]
```

Out:

```
   city gender age death      death_p
1:    a   male  24     0 9.640864e-11
2:    a female  25     0 9.640864e-11
3:    a female  26     1 1.000000e+00
4:    b   male  78     1 1.000000e+00
5:    b   male  65     0 7.582560e-11
6:    b female  34     0 7.582560e-11
7:    a   male  23     0 9.294626e-21
```